# Cannot resolve module 'react' when using npm link and webpack

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I am writing an external module that I would like to require in my project (react-list)

my module is a react component and obviously I have this in top of my file

```
var React = require('react');
```

I'm using npm link, and in my project I'm getting an error from webpack that react doesn't exist inside the node_modules directory INSIDE the external module

```
ERROR in /web/react-list/dist/List/List.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react' in /web/react-list/dist/List
```

why isn't it requiring the react component from my projects node_modules directory?

edit: added my webpack, had to redact the files and directories

```
'use strict';


module.exports = {
context: __dirname,
entry: {

   ....

},
output: {
    path: '../public/js/pages',
    filename: "[name].js"
},
devtool: 'source-map',
resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ["node_modules", ......],
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
},
plugins: [],
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
                presets: ["react", "es2015-loose"]
            }
        }
    ]
}

};
```

edit 2: I found a workaround without using npm link, and simply installing the required package using npm install and then removing the dist directory and replacing it with a soft link on my own without npm's help. Obviously this isn't an ideal way to develop.

edit 3: I reach the dreaded refs must have owner issue https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/refs-must-have-owner.html error if I try to install the dependencies on my package directory, so its either this package doesn't find a react directory or it does but with another react version and nothing works...

Comment: show your `webpack.config`

Comment: @Panther added my webpack config (redacted the files and directories to .....)